# How to access a class method from a property definition

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have a model where I want to use a class method to set the default of for a property:

```
class Organisation(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty()
    code=db.StringProperty(default=generate_code())

    @classmethod
    def generate_code(cls):
        import random
        codeChars='ABCDEF0123456789'
        while True: # Make sure code is unique
            code=random.choice(codeChars)+random.choice(codeChars)+\
                    random.choice(codeChars)+random.choice(codeChars)
            if not cls.all().filter('code = ',code).get(keys_only=True):
                return code
```

But I get a NameError:

```
NameError: name 'generate_code' is not defined
```

How can I access generate_code()?

Comment: Move your generate_code() implementation on the module level. There is zero need why this has to be a class method.

Comment: Thanks - I tried that, but then generate_code() couldn't find Organisation() to query for existing codes. It's close relation to the Organisation object seems to make it sensible to include it in the class if I can.

Comment: In addition: writing a method returning random data for each call is ok but calling it only *ONCE* for generating a once-an-forever default value appears nonsense.

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve? This code looks weird (nicely spoken)

Comment: Each organisation needs a randomly generated code, but this needs to be changed occasionally. It would be nice to generate this automatically when creating the instance, and then be able to call it again via the class.

Comment: As per a previous commment, you will only get that default value generated on parse time of the class, and not on entity creation, rethink what you are doing here.

Comment: Thanks Tim - that makes sense. Given that we are dissuaded from overloading __init__() for models, it looks like there is no way to initialise properties with dynamic values like this. Unless anyone knows better?

Comment: I would keep it simple and create a classmethod , that constructs the instances for you along with any specific/dynamic defaults that you want and always construct new instances this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in a comment, I would use a classmethod to act as a factory and always create you entity through there.  It keeps things simpler and no nasty hooks to get the behaviour you want.

Here is a quick example.

```
class Organisation(db.Model):
    name=db.StringProperty()
    code=db.StringProperty()

    @classmethod
    def generate_code(cls):
        import random
        codeChars='ABCDEF0123456789'
        while True: # Make sure code is unique
            code=random.choice(codeChars)+random.choice(codeChars)+\
                    random.choice(codeChars)+random.choice(codeChars)
            if not cls.all().filter('code = ',code).get(keys_only=True):

        return code

    @classmethod
    def make_organisation(cls,*args,**kwargs):
        new_org = cls(*args,**kwargs)
        new_org.code = cls.generate_code()
        return new_org
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

class Test(object):

    def __new__(cls):
        cls.my_attr = cls.get_code()
        return super(Test, cls).__new__(cls)

    @classmethod
    def get_code(cls):
        return random.randrange(10)

t = Test()
print t.my_attr
```

Comment: We are discouraged from overloading __init__() for Appengine models, does this also apply to __new__()?

Answer (score -1):

You need specify the class name: `Organisation.generate_code()`

Comment: Then I get NameError: name 'Organisation' is not defined.

Comment: Maybe usign __new__ you can make this